# Does this.synchronized protects your from the garbage collector?

Tags: scala, garbage-collection

I have some code that uses `WeakReference`. I had to implement an ugly workaround  to solve the problem, but I wonder if just adding a `this.synchronized` might solve my problem with the garbage collector. Here is the code, the problem is in the function `create`

```
  /**
   * The canonical map.
   */
  var unicityTable = new WeakHashMap[CanonicalType, LightWeightWrapper[CanonicalType]] with SynchronizedMap[CanonicalType, LightWeightWrapper[CanonicalType]]

  /**
   * Create a new element from any object.
   * @param from the object that will be used to generate a new instance of your canonical object.
   */
  def create(from: FromType) = {
    val newElt = makeFrom(from)
      // I wonder if adding a this.synchronized here (and of course removing the test for garbage collection) might solve the problem more elegantly 
      val wrapper = unicityTable.get(newElt)
      wrapper match {
        case Some(w) => w._wrap.get match { // if the element is in the map
          case Some(element) => element // the element was not garbage collected while we obtaining it
          case None => // some how, the wrapped element was garbage collected before we get it, so we recreate it, and put it back
            unicityTable.put(newElt, LightWeightWrapper(newElt))
            newElt
        }
        case None => // the element is not in the map
          unicityTable.put(newElt, LightWeightWrapper(newElt))
          newElt
      }

  }

  class LightWeightWrapper[T <: AnyRef] private (wrap: T) {

    val _wrap = new WeakReference(wrap)

    def wrapped = _wrap.get match {
      case Some(w) => w
      case None => // should never happen 
        throw new IllegalStateException
    }

    override lazy val hashCode = wrapped.hashCode

    override def equals(o: Any): Boolean = o match {
      case LightWeightWrapper(w) => w eq this.wrapped
      case _ => false
    }
  }
```

So the question is: Does garbage collection stop during the execution of a synchronized block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, garbage collection still happens inside of `synchronized`. Also, `this` will already be prevent from being garbage collected because it is on the stack, so you aren't getting any help there either.

I'm not sure what you are doing, but I think maybe you really want to be using `SoftReference` rather than `WeakReference`. Objects that are only referenced by a `WeakReference` may be collected as soon as all hard references are gone. Objects referenced only by a `SoftReference` may be kept until the VM runs low on memory.